# How do I get the absolute path of DocumentsLibrary in Win8/Metro/WinRT?

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, filepath

I have my manifestappx file setup to have access to Documents Library Access and a file association, but when I call

```
Windows::Storage::KnownFolders::DocumentsLibrary->Path
```

Path returns a blank string.  How do I get the path to return properly?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Hmm, a library doesn't have a path, does it?

Comment: It should be equivalent to C:\Users\Michael\Documents.  Since I can loop through the folders/files in DocumentsLibrary but the Path call returns a blank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`DocumentsLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx) is a virtual location representing a collection of different locations and files, it will not have a path:

> Libraries, a concept introduced in Windows 7, allow users to view
>   related user content from a single location. Because the library is a
>   virtual location, folders that are added to or removed from a library
>   continue to exist in their original locations as well.

In addition, the [MSDN documentation for `StorageFolder.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.path.aspx) states:

> Do not rely on this property to access a folder because some folders
>   may not have file-system paths. For example if the folder is a file
>   group, or is backed by a URI, or was picked using the file picker, the
>   folder is not guaranteed to have a file-system path.