# Save SQLite database into Documents Folder win Windows Store App

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I've been writing a Windows 8 Store App using XAML and C# and the target device is a Windows Surface tablet.

Within my application I use a SQLite database.

To create/load the database I use the following code:

```
DBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "MyDatabase.sqlite");
```

However I'd like to store the database in the Documents folder so I tried the follow line of code to replace my line above :

```
DBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.Path, "MyDatabase.sqlite");
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
WinRT information: Access to the specified location (DocumentsLibrary) requires a capability to be declared in the manifest.
```

So I open Package.appxmanifest and select Documents Library under capabilities and under the declarations tab I've added a File Type Association. Then under Properties I've entered 
sqlite in the Name box and .sqlite in the File type box. I've entered no other information on the Package.appxmanifest screen.

Now when I run the app I receive the following error:

```
Could not open database file: MyDatabase.sqlite (CannotOpen)
```

When I inspect Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.Path it equals "". I would have expected the full location path here.

Can anyone help and has anybody ever saved a SQLite database to the documents folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary` does not have a path since it's a virtual location. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11303883/197913) for more details. This could make it impossible to open a SQLite database there, at least using the APIs available in [sqlite-net](https://nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net) library.

Also before using access to Documents library in your Windows Store app keep in mind that for publishing an app with this capability to the store you [need to have a company account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/09/18/what-is-the-difference-between-a-company-vs-individual-account-for-the-windows-store.aspx). With an individual account such applications will be rejected.