# Windows 8: How to read the user documents folder path programmatically (using c )?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

To access the files in the app directory, I am using the following line of code:

```
std::wstring wpath = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data();
```

Similar to the above code, how can I get the documents folder path?
Please suggest a solution that works in Metro app.

Comment: First you have to ask nicely to get access, it is a bit rude to ask for access to all user's documents.  Check the capability requirement.  Then you use Windows::Storage::KnownFolders.

Comment: Hi Hans, Could you please elaborate on capability checking? How can I check the capability? I am not trying to access the documents folder of all or another user. I need to find the documents folder path for the current user.
I tried doing the following, but it returned a blank.

      std::wstring wpath2 = Windows::Storage::KnownFolders::DocumentsLibrary->Path->Data();

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302799/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-path-of-documentslibrary-in-win8-metro-winrt) on Stack Overflow

> Because DocumentsLibrary is a virtual location representing a
>   collection of different locations and files, it will not have a path:
>
> Libraries, a concept introduced in Windows 7, allow users to view
>   related user content from a single location. Because the library is a
>   virtual location, folders that are added to or removed from a library
>   continue to exist in their original locations as well.
>
> In addition, the MSDN documentation for StorageFolder.Path states:
>
> Do not rely on this property to access a folder because some folders
>   may not have file-system paths. For example if the folder is a file
>   group, or is backed by a URI, or was picked using the file picker, the
>   folder is not guaranteed to have a file-system path.

but I suggest you to look at [this](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/SpecialSystemDirectory.cpp) code, search for (line 796):

```
case Win_Documents:
{
    return GetLibrarySaveToPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS,
                                FOLDERID_DocumentsLibrary,
                                aFile);
}
```

your problem seems to be resolved by this piece of code:

```
/*
 * Check to see if we're on Win7 and up, and if so, returns the default
 * save-to location for the Windows Library passed in through aFolderId.
 * Otherwise falls back on pre-win7 GetWindowsFolder.
 */
static nsresult
GetLibrarySaveToPath(int aFallbackFolderId, REFKNOWNFOLDERID aFolderId,
                     nsIFile** aFile)
{
    // Skip off checking for library support if the os is Vista or lower.
    DWORD dwVersion = GetVersion();
    if ((DWORD)(LOBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion))) < 6 ||
        ((DWORD)(LOBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion))) == 6 &&
         (DWORD)(HIBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion))) == 0))
      return GetWindowsFolder(aFallbackFolderId, aFile);

    nsRefPtr<IShellLibrary> shellLib;
    nsRefPtr<IShellItem> savePath;
    HRESULT hr =
        SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder(aFolderId, STGM_READ,
                                     IID_IShellLibrary, getter_AddRefs(shellLib));

    if (shellLib &&
        SUCCEEDED(shellLib->GetDefaultSaveFolder(DSFT_DETECT, IID_IShellItem,
                                                 getter_AddRefs(savePath)))) {
        PRUnichar* str = nullptr;
        if (SUCCEEDED(savePath->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &str))) {
            nsAutoString path;
            path.Assign(str);
            path.AppendLiteral("\\");
            nsresult rv =
                NS_NewLocalFile(path, false, aFile);
            CoTaskMemFree(str);
            return rv;
        }
    }

    return GetWindowsFolder(aFallbackFolderId, aFile);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this code is from the Mozilla sources, so has Mozilla types and functions in it (`nsAutoString`, `nsRefPtr`, `nsresult`, `NS_NewLocalFile`, etc). So you won't be able to use this code verbatim.

Comment: You're right! But if he looks at "SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder" function, maybe he can solve the problem.

Comment: SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder MSDN description says that it is supported for desktop appas only. Sorry that I have not mentioned it in my uqestion clearly that I need to get it working for winRT as well. Do you know a way that works for metro app?

I tried the following, but it returned blank:

    std::wstring wpath2 = Windows::Storage::KnownFolders::DocumentsLibrary->Path->Data();