# Access music files UWP -KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetItemsAsync() doesnt return anything

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, file-access, known-folders

Hey i have the following :

```
 var fileList = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetItemsAsync();
```

It doesn't return any files and i have files in the Music folder. I also have :

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="removableStorage" />
<Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
<Capability Name="MusicLibrary" />
<Capability Name="HomeGroup" />
<Capability Name="RemovableDevices" />
```

I dont know why it doesnt return any files/ exception ? Any suggestions ? I also tried FolderPicker to get all files in a folder , but same result.

Comment: Although you may have access to the MusicLibrary, the files inside it might be hidden. Can you try creating a file in the library and then run `GetItemsAsync()` again to see if your created file exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form the code you've posted, it seems you are using wrong capabilities.

> The **musicLibrary** capability must include the **uap** namespace when you declare it in your app's package manifest as shown below.
>
> ```
> <Capabilities><uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary"/></Capabilities>
> ```

For more info, please see [App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

So you can chane your `Package.appxmanifest` like the following:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
  <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
  <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
</Capabilities>
```

And then you should be able to get the files and subfolders in the music library.

```
var fileList = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetItemsAsync();
if (fileList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in fileList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```

The Music Library typically has the following path.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Music
```

You can check if you have files under this path. And also you can check the path with the following code.

```
var musicLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Music);
Debug.WriteLine(musicLibrary.SaveFolder.Path);
```

This will output the path of the known folder, which is the folder in a library where new files are saved by default. For more info, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38888275/5506161).

Comment: Thanks , i added uap in the Components(had to find out u have to save and build after every capability , else if you rebuild it automatically rerolls what you edited) and i tried.So its really interesting that fileList does not have anything while mouseover and inspect it while debugging , but in the loop it shows there are files ? What is this sorcery , sir ?

Comment: @ChrisTanev This is because the `fileList` is not a managed object, and by default the **Debugger type** for a UWP project is "**Managed Only**". So you can't inspect it while debugging. You can try to change the  **Debugger type** to "**Mixed (Managed and Native)**" like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzbZ1.png) for inspecting.

Comment: Zuo Thanks ! Only problem i have now , is that the components i deleted  , are sometimes adding themselves back to the manifest automatically , so i have to delete them again and build proj. Any thoughts ?